# How to set up a headless X server with Xdummy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cuda, ubuntu-server

I have some demand loaded EC2 nodes that run my software that uses a proprietary library that makes heavy use of CUDA.

However, the latest version of the proprietary library requires 
an XServer running.  Previous versions didn't need this.

I came across Xdummy.  How do I set that up?  I've tried following this:
http://cosmolinux.no-ip.org/raconetlinux2/dummy_radeon_nvidia.html

But the best I've managed is:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

How do I get this running?

Comment: How is this either related to CUDA or on topic for [SO]?

Answer (score 1):

Run a version of X that supports [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).  This will emulate a screen in software that can be connected to with a VNC client. [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) is another option.